# Prototype is restricted in Firefox 67

Tags: javascript, security, firefox, iframe, cross-domain

Since Firefox version 67, users can't access the system I'm working on due to errors thrown when trying to access some variables.

[image: Error we receive whenever we try to clone]

the Learn more links to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied)

As you can see, lodash clone is failing when trying to access property type of given object.
I also noticed prototype is Restricted for the object.

The object is received from a function that is exposed in an object that is being received from an iFrame inside the website (the object is exposed via onMessageReceived...)

Anyone is experiencing anything similar?
Any clue how can I fix this bug?

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't occur for all objects, in which case, can you post a [MCVE]? What does the Learn More link to?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, the Learn more links to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied)
I will try to get a minimal reproducible example, but it's really hard to extract this example from the codebase

Comment: *"the Learn more links to here"* Questions must be self-contained, since external links rot. Quote the relevant parts of the linked content *in* the question.

Comment: What is the origin of the page this code runs on? What is the origin of the iframe? The error relates to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), indicating that you're trying to access an object cross-origin, which is quite correctly denied.

Comment: It is true, the iframe is in another domain (subdomain of the current domain), I'm talking with the devs of the iframe site so they will add Access-Control-Allow-Origin for us, it takes some time some I'm trying to find another way to solve it (I also tried to allow access by modifying the response but I'm having some troubles doing so since any plugin that I use don't modify headers for iframes)